# Is there a recommended workflow for dealing with bugs in the MSF for Agile 2013.3 TFS template?

Tags: agile

I've been working with the MSF for Scrum project template for a while now and created a new project using the MSF for Agile 2013.3 template.

It seems a lot simpler but it doesn't allow me to add bugs to an iteration.

I've read somewhere that we should be creating a linked User Story and adding that to a sprint but part of that process is to "resolve" the bug with a reason of copied to backlog but it seems a bit unnatural to resolve something which hasn't been started.

All the ALM guidance I've been able to find is for the 2013.2 and earlier template so hasn't had this field included. Is there any official guidance or unofficial guidance anywhere about the recommended workflow for bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended workflow has always been to create a linked User Story and mark the Bug as Resolve-Copied To Backlog.  If you look back at older process templates they all have the reason "Copied To Backlog" (I just checked the 2012 template to be sure, and it's there).

Comment: Ahh okay, I looked at some of the docs and they didn't seem to have that reason, I didn't have access to the old template to check that. We can work with that process. Thanks